# How do I add Voip Calling feature in my flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, voip, voip-android

I want to add VoIP calling in my Flutter app like Swiggy/uber,where they can call from app to a phone number, please help me out. THANK YOU!

Have'nt found any reliable documentation yet.

Comment: You'll need a service provider, and many of them provide flutter SDKs.  See "voip" as a search in the pub.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.